# How would I create a Safari-compatible Transition Transform Scale without breaking the container's border-radius

Tags: css, transform, scale, transition, border-radius

I have an image that I would like to scale on hover. The image's container has a border-radius. The image scales fine on most browsers, but on Safari, the container's border-radius gets removed when the transition is being applied. I have created a jsfiddle demonstrating this behavior.

https://jsfiddle.net/jt9u7qhw/

I tried applying the transition times for the specific properties transform and border-radius with and without webkit,

```
.element {
    transition: transform 1s, border-radius 1s;
    -webkit-transition: transform 1s, border-radius 1s;
    transition-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
}
```

But this didn't make a difference, how do I preserve the border-radius during this transition?

Answer (score 0):

Although this breaks using `transform: scale` and  `-webkit-transition: transform 1s, border-radius 1s` or `-webkit-transition: all 1s` a potential workaround since this is using backround images is to change the background size on hover instead of scaling it up,

```
.element {
    background-size: auto 100%; # set width to auto works in this case b/c landscape pic
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-out;
    transition: all 1s ease-out;
}

.container:hover .element,
.container:focus .element {
    background-size: auto 110%;
}
```

Working demo, https://jsfiddle.net/khzu0t61/